# Unable to add resource to CloudFormation template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cognito, amazon-iam

I have a CloudFormation template. The problem area is the very last Resource statement, but I can not figure out why.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Description: CloudFormation Template for Amazon Cognito

Resources:

  DummyIdentityPool:
    Type: AWS::Cognito::IdentityPool
    Properties:
      AllowUnauthenticatedIdentities: false
      IdentityPoolName: Dummy

  DummyUserPool:
    Type: AWS::Cognito::UserPool
    Properties:
      DeletionProtection: 'ACTIVE'
      EnabledMfas:
        - 'SMS_MFA' #SMS_MFA can only be enabled if SMS configuration is provided.
      MfaConfiguration: 'ON'
      SmsConfiguration:
        ExternalId: Test
        SnsCallerArn: !GetAtt SnsSmsCallerRole.Arn
        SnsRegion: !Ref AWS::Region

  SnsSmsCallerRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service: cognito-idp.amazonaws.com
            Action: sts:AssumeRole
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: CognitoSNSPublish
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: '2012-10-17'
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - sns:Publish
                Resource:
                  - Fn::Sub: arn:aws:sns:*:*:*
```

The template deploys when I make the Resource under the 'CognitoSNSPublish' policy a wildcard, like `Resource: *`, and it works, it deploys.
Here's the problem, when I change the Resource to be specific, like `Resource: arn:aws:sns:*:*:*`, or `Resource: arn:aws:sns:sns:*:*`, or `Resource: arn:aws:sns:<my-region>:*:*`, or `Resource: arn:aws:sns:<my-region>:<my-account-id>:*`, it fails with the following error:

```
Resource handler returned message: "Role does not have permission to publish with SNS (Service: CognitoIdentityProvider, Status Code: 400, Request ID: 338a4-9de1-47f0536218f0)" (RequestToken: 101a93b5-q0lo-5e4c-810d-lol22j2nsa2, HandlerErrorCode: InvalidRequest)
```

Comment: What `Fn::Sub: arn:aws:sns:*:*:*` is supposed to do? You are not using `Sub` at all?

Comment: i realise that sub is not doing anything, i was actually using sub to append my aws account id and region. i tried using it without sub, like: ```Resource: arn:aws:sns:*:*:*```

Comment: If `Resource: *` works, why not use it? What's wrong with it?

Comment: sure, that works, but i want to restrict the policy to only allow publish action to sns only and no other aws resources. this way cognito can only publish to one fixed resource - sns. i am trying to follow the convention of least privilege.

Comment: `sns:Publish` only works with `sns`, so its automatically restricted to `sns`.

Comment: that's exactly the answer i was looking for. as long as the publish action is happening only for sns, that works. thanks @Marcin

Comment: No problem. I will make an answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sns:Publish` action works only with `sns`. It can't be used with any other service. Thus `Resource: *` will effectively limit your action to `sns` only.